# change url base on parameter with htaccess on codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

this is for ecommerce website,i am using codeigniter 3.I want the url for the shop page to be like `https://coffee.com/shop/7sp` where `7sp` is the shop name (every shop have difference name). Right now the url is `https://coffee.com/shop/page/shops/4` where `4` is the shop id for `7sp` shop.I tried many ways to change the url using htaccess but none of it working because i am not very good using htaccess and also not sure if it its the right way to do it (by using the htaccess).

.htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://coffee.com/shop/$1 [R,L]
```

config.php :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://coffee.com/shop/
```

controller :

```
  public function shops($seller_id='')
  {
   $this->data['pList'] = $this->product_model->get_productType(null,$seller_id,null,null);
   $this->data['seller'] = $this->user_model->get_detail_seller($seller_id);
   $this->template->load('layouts/main', 'pages/shop_paging',$this->data);
  }
```

Comment: there are a lot of guides about .htaccess on the web. Look for one.

Comment: best way to test htaccess code in real time, https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/